# How can multiple people upload to Google Drive with the same "Last modified" name on each upload?

Tags: google-drive

We run a service that involves uploading deliverables to our clients' Google Drives.

Our client shares a Google Drive folder with us, and we have multiple contractors uploading the files.

**The problem:** We don't want the uploaded files labeled with whatever name the contractors happen to have on their account, e.g. `"Alice Awesome"`, `"Bob Briggs"`, `"Cathy Cross"` *(this name appears next to the "Last modified" date in the Google Drive web interface)*

Is there a way to ensure the creator name of all uploaded files is `"Our Business Name"`, regardless of who uploads them?

The obvious way seems to be to have all contractors log into the same Google account, *but Google explicitly warns against doing this*.

Comment: Really, that sounds counter-intuitive.  What if someone makes a mistake, how are you going out who it was.

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> Is there a way to ensure the creator name of all uploaded files is "Our Business Name", regardless of who uploads them?

While the users use the Google Drive apps, it's not possible. One option is to make copies of the files using an account having the name that you want.

Another option is to use Google Apps Script to create a web-app that is executed using an account having the name that you want that allows that anyone that run.